# Unable to horizontally center a TextView

Tags: android

I have a `TextView` inside a LinearLayout and i want to align it in center of the page but its not happening, i have tried the following:

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#80000000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="User Name"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: check out my answer, I hope I can be a help

Comment: "Unable to horizontally center a TextView", thats what is what your question title says and " i want to align it in center of the page " thats what your question explanation says. You yourself are not clear what exactly you want to write and you are downvoting the answers for no proper reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the TextView layout_width to "match_parent", the issue is that "gravity" works only for the child of the View in this case the "text" it self, hence if you specify the object width as just to wrap its content, it means there's no space to center to, filling the whole parent and using "gravity" center would do the trick.

The other thing you can do is changing the "android:gravity" property to "android:layout_gravity" and center horizontal, this way you are telling the TextView itself to move to the center...

As best practice always try to use RelativeLayouts and avoid LinearLayouts, they provide a better way to manipulate Views position and are "device size fragmentation" friendly, RelativeLayout have plenty of methods to position views on the most common positions including center, top, bottom etc...

Hope this Helps.

Regards!

Comment: I dont want to align text in center thats already there, i want to align the `TextView` as box in the center of the screen and `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"` is already applied but is not working.

Comment: In that case, do not use the LinearLayout as root element, and go for RelativeLayout, and make use of the "android:layout_centerHorizontal="true""

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the *layout*. Linear Layout is meant for **displaying ui components in rows**. If you want to center your textview using you layout, I suggest changing the layout to **Relative Layout**.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:gravity="center" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#80000000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="User Name"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you cant set the property android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" for a LinearLayout. To make it centered you need to make layout height and width to match_parent like below,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#80000000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="User Name"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```